# Componente p:panelGrid não renderiza, só exibe textos

Tags: primefaces

Tenho um `p:panelGrid` que recebe dados dinâmicos à medida que são recebidos pelo método `onItemchanged` mencionado no código. No entanto, conforme a imagem, o componente não renderiza e só exibe os textos.

Já tentei com Glassfish e Jboss e o resultado é o mesmo.

Página (JSF- XHTML):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
          xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
        <h:head>
            <title>PollGF</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h:form>
                <h:commandButton value="Start" actionListener="#{comm.init()}" />
                <br/>
                <h:panelGrid id="grid" columns="7" style="margin-top: 20px">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column colspan="7">Soybeans Quotes</p:column>
                        </p:row>
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column>Description</p:column>
                            <p:column>Last</p:column>
                            <p:column>Diff</p:column>
                            <p:column>%</p:column>
                            <p:column>Close</p:column>
                            <p:column>Ask</p:column>
                            <p:column>Bid</p:column>
                        </p:row>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column >#{comm.description}</p:column>
                        <p:column >#{comm.last}</p:column>
                        <p:column >#{comm.diff}</p:column>
                        <p:column >#{comm.variation}</p:column>
                        <p:column >#{comm.close}</p:column>
                        <p:column >#{comm.ask}</p:column>
                        <p:column >#{comm.bid}</p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:poll interval="1" update="grid" />
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </html>
```

Managed Bean:

```
import br.com.jpoint.periods.SoyNov4;
import com.pretty_tools.dde.DDEException;
import com.pretty_tools.dde.client.DDEClientConversation;
import com.pretty_tools.dde.client.DDEClientEventListener;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "comm")
@SessionScoped
public class Comm {

    private String description;
    private String last;
    private String diff;
    private String variation;
    private String close;
    private String ask;
    private String bid;

    private String code;
    private String value;


    final CountDownLatch eventDisconnect = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final DDEClientConversation conversation = new DDEClientConversation();
    private static final String SERVICE = "TWSVR";
    private static final String TOPIC = "CMA";

    static final String[] items = {
        "0030ZS*1;212", "0030ZS*1;41", "0030ZS*1;1", "0030ZS*1;6", "0030ZS*1;7", "0030ZS*1;25", "0030ZS*1;3", "0030ZS*1;4",
        "0030ZS*2;212", "0030ZS*2;41", "0030ZS*2;1", "0030ZS*2;6", "0030ZS*2;7", "0030ZS*2;25", "0030ZS*2;3", "0030ZS*2;4"
//        "0030ZS*3;212", "0030ZS*3;41", "0030ZS*3;1", "0030ZS*3;6", "0030ZS*3;7", "0030ZS*3;25", "0030ZS*3;3", "0030ZS*3;4",
//        "0030ZS*4;212", "0030ZS*4;41", "0030ZS*4;1", "0030ZS*4;6", "0030ZS*4;7", "0030ZS*4;25", "0030ZS*4;3", "0030ZS*4;4",
//        "0030ZS*5;212", "0030ZS*5;41", "0030ZS*5;1", "0030ZS*5;6", "0030ZS*5;7", "0030ZS*5;25", "0030ZS*5;3", "0030ZS*5;4",
//        "0030ZS*6;212", "0030ZS*6;41", "0030ZS*6;1", "0030ZS*6;6", "0030ZS*6;7", "0030ZS*6;25", "0030ZS*6;3", "0030ZS*6;4",
//        "0030ZS*7;212", "0030ZS*7;41", "0030ZS*7;1", "0030ZS*7;6", "0030ZS*7;7", "0030ZS*7;25", "0030ZS*7;3", "0030ZS*7;4",
//        "0030ZS*8;212", "0030ZS*8;41", "0030ZS*8;1", "0030ZS*8;6", "0030ZS*8;7", "0030ZS*8;25", "0030ZS*8;3", "0030ZS*8;4",
//        "0030ZS*9;212", "0030ZS*9;41", "0030ZS*9;1", "0030ZS*9;6", "0030ZS*9;7", "0030ZS*9;25", "0030ZS*9;3", "0030ZS*9;4",
//        "0030ZS*10;212", "0030ZS*10;41", "0030ZS*10;1", "0030ZS*10;6", "0030ZS*10;7", "0030ZS*10;25", "0030ZS*10;3", "0030ZS*10;4",
//        "0030ZS*11;212", "0030ZS*11;41", "0030ZS*11;1", "0030ZS*11;6", "0030ZS*11;7", "0030ZS*11;25", "0030ZS*11;3", "0030ZS*11;4",
//        "0030ZS*12;212", "0030ZS*12;41", "0030ZS*12;1", "0030ZS*12;6", "0030ZS*12;7", "0030ZS*12;25", "0030ZS*12;3", "0030ZS*12;4",
//        "0030ZS*13;212", "0030ZS*13;41", "0030ZS*13;1", "0030ZS*13;6", "0030ZS*13;7", "0030ZS*13;25", "0030ZS*13;3", "0030ZS*13;4"
    };

    public Comm() {
    }

    public void init() throws DDEException {
//        System.loadLibrary("JavaDDE");
//        System.loadLibrary("JavaDDEx64");
        conversation.connect(SERVICE, TOPIC);
        conversation.setEventListener(new DDEClientEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDisconnect() {
                System.out.println("onDisconnect()");
                eventDisconnect.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemChanged(String topic, String item, String data) {
                System.out.println("onItemChanged(" + topic + "\t" + item + "\t" + data + ")");
                code = item;
                value = data;

                //******************************************************
                if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(SoyNov4.DESCRIPTION)){
                    description = data;
                } else if (item.equalsIgnoreCase(SoyNov4.LAST)){
                    last = data;
                } else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(SoyNov4.DIFF)){
                    diff = data;
                } else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(SoyNov4.VARIATION)){
                    variation = data;
                } else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(SoyNov4.CLOSE)){
                    close = data;
                } else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(SoyNov4.ASK)){
                    ask = data;
                } else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(SoyNov4.BID)){
                    bid = data;
                }
                //******************************************************


                try {
                    if ("stop".equalsIgnoreCase(data)) {
                        conversation.stopAdvice(item);
                    }
                } catch (DDEException e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
                }
            }

        });
        //**********************************************//
        for (String i : items) {
            conversation.startAdvice(i);
        }
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(String last) {
        this.last = last;
    }

    public String getDiff() {
        return diff;
    }

    public void setDiff(String diff) {
        this.diff = diff;
    }

    public String getVariation() {
        return variation;
    }

    public void setVariation(String variation) {
        this.variation = variation;
    }

    public String getClose() {
        return close;
    }

    public void setClose(String close) {
        this.close = close;
    }

    public String getAsk() {
        return ask;
    }

    public void setAsk(String ask) {
        this.ask = ask;
    }

    public String getBid() {
        return bid;
    }

    public void setBid(String bid) {
        this.bid = bid;
    }

}
```

[image: só os textos são exibidos]

Answer (score 0):

Observe que ao invés de `<p:panelGrid>` você colocou `<h:panelGrid>` isso justifica não aparecer as bordas automaticamente.

Mas se você quer usar `<h:panelGrid>` a borda será exibida somente se você atribuir um valor
para a propriedade `border` desse componente, como por exemplo:

```
<h:panelGrid id="grid" collumns="7" border="1" style="margin-top: 20px" >
  <!-- o conteúdo aqui -->
</h:panelGrid>
```

Ou então aplicar regras de CSS para esse componente (`<h:panelGrid>`).

Comment: Valeu pela dica @Luídne, mas, não funcionou mesmo assim. De qq forma, acabei usando uma html <table> mesmo e funcionou legal. Apenas coloquei dentro as referências ao bean JSF. Ex.: <li>#{bean.attributeName}</li>